# How to remove port 3000 from URLs in production Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using both `_path` and `_url` helpers in a Rails 5.2.3 app. Everything works in development. When I deploy it in production, the URLs that were set with `_url` helpers are printing out in the HTML as `https://127.0.0.1` instead of to the actual host.

I tried adding this to `config/environments/production.rb`:

```rb
config.action_controller.default_url_options = { host: 'example.com' }
```

but that turns the URLs into `https://example.com:3000`, which breaks the links. (Puma is running on port 3000, but it's behind nginx, which is serving on port 80.)

Does anyone know what might be causing that? `RAILS_ENV` is set to `production`.

Comment: Probably a dumb question, but you're not accessing your site at `example.com:3000`, are you?

Comment: The live site is at a real domain. I'm just replacing it with `example.com` as an example. The site itself is at a URL like `https://example.com/`. The links that are generated by the `*_url` helpers point to `https://example.com:3000/some/path/here`. Those don't load, because nginx is in front of Puma, and visitors only access port 80.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this on some sort of sample app?

Comment: This is what I have instead and it works config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'http://example.com', port: 3000 }

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
 config.action_controller.default_url_options = { host: 'example.com' }
```

try this in the production.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'your_host.com'
```